# Get inserted table identity value and update another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables with foreign key constraint on TableB on TablesAs KeyA column. I was doing manual inserts till now as they were only few rows to be added. Now i need to do a bulk insert, so my question if i insert multiple rows in TableA how can i get all those identity values and insert them into TableB along with other column values. Please see the script below.

```
INSERT INTO Tablea
       ([KeyA]
       ,[Value] )
    SELECT 4 ,'StateA'
UNION ALL
SELECT 5 ,'StateB'
UNION ALL
SELECT 6 ,'StateC'

INSERT INTO Tableb
       ([KeyB]
       ,[fKeyA] //Get value from the inserted row from TableA
       ,[Desc])
SELECT 1 ,4,'Value1'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 ,5,'Value2'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 ,6, 'Value3'
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Look at the [OUTPUT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx). I'd provide an answer but you don't seem too interested in rewarding people for helping you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the OUTPUT clause of INSERT to do this. Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (id [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, Val int)

CREATE TABLE #new (id [int], val int)

INSERT INTO #temp (val) OUTPUT inserted.id, inserted.val INTO #new VALUES (5), (6), (7) 

SELECT id, val FROM #new

DROP TABLE #new
DROP TABLE #temp
```

The result set returned includes the inserted IDENTITY values.

Comment: This seems very interesting.  Can I use the OUTPUT clause to reliably get the inserted IDs in the order they were inserted?  I'd really like to insert a large table of data and return the ID numbers in the correct order without having to retransmit an entire data package.

Comment: @Ted it's a set, why does order matter? The ID value in the output clause will be correlated with the value that was assigned to that value in the initial insert. A table is an unordered set of rows, so don't get too hung up on order - the important thing is that if StateA got an identity value of 200 during the insert, that in the second table 200 will be associated with the correct row. It doesn't do this based on "order."

Comment: I'm writing a C# program that inserts a few million rows using a table parameter insert.  Is it possible to get back the correct identity value for each row and assign them to my C# objects reliably?  I know I can simply retrieve the scope_identity() value and assign each row's ID as `(ending_identity_value - (number_of_rows_inserted - row_number))`.  However I'm concerned that I may be being too clever and my code won't be reliable in all cases, so most of the time I just design the program so it won't need identity numbers after the insert.

Comment: @TedSpence I saw a SO question on this where they needed to merge additional data but I cannot find it.  The answer was to output the iden and additional column(s) using merge.

Comment: You know what, I'll ask this as a new question and I'd love to get all your contributions to help resolve it :)

Comment: @TedSpence - FWIW, I normally pass multiple TVPs into a single stored procedure and correlate them using MERGE. MERGE allows you to include things you didn't insert into the OUTPUT clause - so you can issue rows a unique ID on the way in, then correlate them that way.

Answer (score 0):

[Scope identity sometimes returns incorrect value](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/328811/scope-identity-sometimes-returns-incorrect-value).  See the use of `OUTPUT` in the workarounds section.

Comment: SCOPE_IDENTITY() wouldn't be valid here anyway - notice the initial command inserts multiple rows; SCOPE_IDENTITY() only returns the last.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Yes, that was quite clear in the OP.  The reference provides both an example of using `OUTPUT` and a heads up for those handling a single row at a time that they may wish to explore an alternative to the standard techniques: `MAX( ID )`, `@@IDENTITY`, `IDENT_CURRENT( 'TABLE_NAME' )`, `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.  Thanks for rewarding me with your comment.

Comment: That wasn't necessarily for you, but for other readers as well.